# How to loop each days of month from computed value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a sign-up form where a user must select the date of birth.

I am looping through a list of months and output day accordingly.

```js
let selectedMonth = 'April'

new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    months: [
      {month: 'January', days: 31},
      {month: 'February', days: 28},
      {month: 'March', days: 31},
      {month: 'April', days: 30},
      {month: 'May', days: 31},
      {month: 'June', days: 30},
      {month: 'July', days: 31},
      {month: 'August', days: 31},
      {month: 'September', days: 30},
      {month: 'October', days: 31},
      {month: 'November', days: 30},
      {month: 'December', days: 31},
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filterDays() {
      return this.months.filter(function(value) {
        return value.month === selectedMonth;
      });
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>  

<div id = "app">
  <select id="dob">
    <option v-for="day in filterDays" :value="day.days">{{ day.days }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The above program just outputs `<option value = "30">30</option>` instead of looping `day in 30`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filterDays` returns a **month object collection**. If you want to loop on a number, use it as the loop source: `filterDays[0].days`.

```
<option v-for="day in filterDays[0].days" :value="day">{{ day }}</option>
```

Or fix the computed function by returning the days there.

```
computed: {
  filterDays() {
    // Select the first item here.
    const month = this.months.filter(value => value.month === selectedMonth)[0];

    // If the month was found, return its days, otherwise, undefined.
    return month && month.days;
  }
},
```

Comment: @Sanjay I fixed it.